# A wider looking zero, for tensors?

Tags: symbols, size

I am looking to distinguish between the zero vector for geometric 3D vectors and the zero tensors of linear second order tensors. Basically, I am looking for a bold-faced 0 that is wider than `${\bf 0}$`. I have seen this in textbooks and have done quite a bit of Googling but to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can stretch out `\textbf{0}` (or whatever `0` symbol you use; perhaps `$\mathbf{0}$`) horizontally by a factor of 20%, say:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

0 \textbf{0} \scalebox{1.2}[1]{\textbf{0}}

\end{document}
```

`\scalebox{<hfactor>}[<vfactor>]{<stuff>}` scales stuff `h`orizontally/`v`ertically based on the supplied `factor`s. If no `<vfactor>` is supplied, the aspect ratio is maintained.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `\mathsf` (sans serif) for tensors—even better would be bold version of `\mathsf` defined as `\mathbsf` with

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathbsf}{OT1}{cmss}{bx}{n}
```

Note that bold sans serif is recommended for tensors by an (hardly ever followed) ISO standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this in math mode, you have the `\mathlarger` command, from `relsize`. You only have the size above. As this limitation is not valid in textmode, if you want more, you have to leave math mode first, choose a still larger size in text mode and enter math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, relsize}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathbf{0}\enspace \mathlarger{\mathbf{0}}\enspace \text{\larger[3]{$\mathbf{0}$}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]